# Launch event function on a specific element of the FOR loop

Tags: javascript

How to apply "color" function JUST to the element that has been affected by "mouseover".

```
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("issue-link");
    var colors = ["red","green","orange","yellow","satin","grey","purple","brown","sky-blue","dark-green"];
    var message = "<p>Hello!</p>";

    function color() {
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var colorNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        els[i].innerHTML = message;
        els[i].style.color = colors[colorNr];
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].onmouseover = color;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the function, the element you hooked the event on is available as `this`. So:

```
function color() {
    this.innerHTML = message;
    this.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Live example:

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("issue-link");
var colors = ["red", "green", "orange", "yellow", "satin", "grey", "purple", "brown", "sky-blue", "dark-green"];
var message = "<p>Hello!</p>";

function color() {
  this.innerHTML = message;
  this.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].onmouseover = color;
}
```

```html
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
<div class="issue-link">link</div>
```

---

Also note that by not declaring `i` in your loop, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables.

Also note how I used `colors.length` rather than a hardcoded `9`, so that if you add a color to the array, the code automatically handles it without your having to change the `9` to a `10`.

Comment: Is it necessary to re-set `.innerHTML` at each call where  `<p>Hello!</p>` is already `.innerHTML`?

Comment: @guest: No, but it's fairly harmless and avoids complicating the code. We could certainly add a check of some kind before doing it to see if the element in question had already had it set by a previous call, if we had some reason for doing so.

Comment: @Jonasw Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

**The real answer ( T. J. Crowder was faster ):**

```
function color() {
    var colorNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    this.style.color = colors[colorNr];        
}
```

In a function called by an event handler, this is the clicked object...

**My Original, completely missinterpreted answer:**

You need to bind the color somehow to your element. My code does it trough a binding of this, there are other possibilities like using an IIFE or using Array.prototype.forEach. By the way, i extended your code a bit without noticing...

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("issue-link");
var colors = ["red","green","orange","yellow","satin","grey","purple","brown","sky-blue","dark-green"];
var message = "<p>Hello!</p>";

function color() {
this.el.style.color=this.color;   
}

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
els[i].onmouseover = color.bind({el:els[i],color:colors[i]||"blue"});
}
```

Comment: `bind` is rather over the top here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i think i should stop answering for today. Im already solving non existend problems...